# Struct constructor call is ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++14

I have 2 constructors in struct 'matrix'.

```
matrix(const unsigned int m, const unsigned int n);
matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<double>> &elements);
```

When I call it like this

```
matrix mat({{1},{1}});
```

It throws error

```
call of overloaded ‘matrix(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous
note: candidate: matrix::matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<double> >&)
note: candidate: matrix::matrix(const matrix&)
```

So, it thinks, that {{1},{1}} - is 'matrix' object, but how?

Comment: @AnT, yes, because I have vector of vectors. I can even type {{1,2,3}, {1,2}, {1}} and it will be compiled.

Comment: @AnT, yes, my mistake, thanks.

Comment: `{1}` is a `vector<double>`, `{{1}, {1}}` is `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`. If you remove your first constructor,  the code should still compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, it thinks, that {{1},{1}} - is 'matrix' object, but how?

In your sample code

```
matrix mat({{1},{1}});
```

you *explicitly told* the compiler to try and match that expression to a `matrix` constructor.

It doesn't "think" the expression `{{1},{1}}` is a matrix, it's trying to make it into one, because you asked it to.

As for why you get the error (which isn't what you asked, but seems worth mentioning), it's because

```
vector<double> v{1};
```

is a valid declaration of a vector with a single value (1.0), and so

```
vector<vector<double>> vv{{1},{1}};
```

is *also* a valid declaration of a vector containing two element vectors, each with a single `double` element of value 1.0, and so finally

```
mat{{{1},{1}}};
```

would be a valid match for the vector constructor. Since this conversion is allowed implicitly, we're allowed to rewrite

```
mat m({{1},{1}});
```

as

```
mat m(mat{{{1},{1}}});
```

and hence the ambiguity. Note the round and curly brackets carefully.

You can either make the constructor implicit, or just get used to uniform initialization style and write

```
mat m{{{1},{1}}};
```

in the first place.

Comment: But why it tries to convert this ({{1},{1}}) construction into a 'matrix'? Is that how structs working? Before that I used only classes and never encountered with this.

Comment: You told it to! Any statement like `mat m(EXPRESSION);` as asking the compiler to create a new `mat` from `EXPRESSION`. That's identical for both structs and classes, and none of this will change if you turn your struct into a class (just make sure everything is public).

Comment: @Useless: you should mention that `{{1}, {1}}` finds the first constructor - that's the cause of the ambiguity!

Comment: @Useless, ok, but when I try to call it with '{{1,1}}' or with '{{1}, {2}, {3}}', it doesn't want to call another constructor. Why? What's the difference?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I thought so. But for some reason, compiler talks about the matrix(const matrix&) constructor, not the matrix(const int, const int)...

Comment: `{1,1}` can't match your vector<vector> constructor, only the unsigned one. `{{1}, {2}, {3}}` can't match the unsigned constructor, only the vector one. I'm kind of concerned that you're throwing random collections of curly braces at this class with no clear idea which constructor they match or why.

Comment: @Useless oh, ok, I attentively read the answer, now it's clear to me.

Comment: And I've gone back and re-written to clarify the role played by all those brackets and braces.

Comment: What you've done there, `mat{{1},{1}}` would not work, because it would only match the two-parameter constructor and not the vector constructor. Unless you are supposing that `mat` is of type `vector<...>` instead of `matrix`, which is not clear to me from the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I damaged my curly-brace-nesting while reformatting. Sigh.

Answer (score 3):

When calling `matrix mat({{1},{1}})` the compiler finds these two ambiguous construction paths:

- Call the `vector<vector>>` constructor by constructing two vectors with one elements inside a vector.
- Implicitly create a temporary matrix with the first constructor, then construct `mat` with that temporary.

  1. Create a temporary matrix from `matrix(const unsigned int m, const unsigned int n)`. *(The first `{1}` is matched to `m`, the second `{1}`is matched to `n`.)*
  2. Try to construct `mat` from the temporary by using `matrix(const matrix&)`.

Marking the first (or both) constructor(s) as `explicit` will unambiguously make `matrix mat({{1},{1}})` invoke the...

```
matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<double>> &elements);
```

...one.

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RcmBIFfQ94rtY1DK)

Comment: `Implicitly create a temporary matrix with the first constructor`, it means, that {{m}, {n}} turns into m, n?

Comment: @VladMarkushin: it's clear from the output here: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6qfAZ5Y7It0k5OJE - basically, yes.

Comment: @VladMarkushin: I updated my answer - is it clear now?

Comment: Marking the first constructor `explicit` will not help, because you are in list-initialization world, where `explicit` makes no difference for overload resolution, but only whether or not an `explicit` constructor is allowed to be invoked.

Comment: .. interesting though, that only GCC marks this code as illegal. Clang accepts. I think that GCC is correct to mark the code as illegal. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ab8aa4bc6953454

Comment: This difference can be more easily demonstrated with this code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef65c26000452db3 . This is a clear part of the Standard, which clang seems to be violating here.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: interesting - did you submit a bug report?

Comment: I seem to remember a defect report about this by Richard (in general, whether ill-formed implicit conversion sequences are actually ones, or whether they make a function inviable), but I can't find it on the issues list. Perhaps Richard has more information and has implemented it this way on purpose.